# Convert numpy array to DMatrix in xgboost

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

I want to convert my array train set and label to DMatrix for training.

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label=y_train)
```

Here `x_train.shape = (13619575, 45)`.

But when I ran this code, the jupyter notebook kernel crashed while my memory still have 8GB.

I have attempted to reduce it to 70% records. But it still crashed. 
Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your dataset has too many samples

Comment: Shall I must write the train set to txt of svm format and read it from disk ?

Comment: `set to txt of svm format` ? Don't get it

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to this issue :
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/163

> There will be duplicated memory copy between numpy and xgb.DMatrix,
> if you want to save memory, try to convert the data into LibSVM format
> and xgb.DMatrix support direct loading from the textformat without
> involving numpy. Or simply use a machine with more RAM.

You could use dump_svmlight_file to dump to SVM file format

Example given here :
https://www.kaggle.com/c/telstra-recruiting-network/discussion/18223

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Id'] = np.arange(10)
df['F1'] = np.random.rand(10,)
df['F2'] = np.random.rand(10,)
df['Target'] = map(lambda x: -1 if x < 0.5 else 1, np.random.rand(10,))

X = df[np.setdiff1d(df.columns,['Id','Target'])]
y = df.Target

print df

dump_svmlight_file(X,y,'smvlight.dat',zero_based=True,multilabel=False)
```

Though I have a problem for now: dumping is very slow for a 4Gb dataset, a faster way must exist.